# What is the sense of placing in function parameter array a size?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int iStrangeArrayOutter[11];
    iStrangeArrayOutter[7] = 5; 
    testFunc (iStrangeArrayOutter);
    return 0;
}

int testFunc (int iStrangeArray[3])
{
    printf ("%d\r\n", iStrangeArray[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

What does the `int iStrangeArray[3]` part of the function declaration reveal?

Comment: Actually nothing. You can write `(int iStrangeArray[3])`, `(int iStrangeArray[3000])` or `(int iStrangeArray[])` or even `(int *iStrangeArray)`,it's the same thing.

Comment: It does if you have a 2d array.

Comment: does this code compile? it would seem the "iStrangeArray[7]" inside testFunc is out of range.

Comment: @self What exactly would it do then?

Comment: @jayjay it compiles without any warnings on gcc4.4 clang 3.0 and MSVC 10

Comment: OK, then maybe it does mean nothing!

Comment: @Zaibis It would set the width of the array which is required for element access. Try it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Incorrect, c11 brings optional bounds checking, which is implemented in gcc 4.9.

Comment: @self : I already have removed my comment, I didn't realizse this at first.

Comment: @Zaibis To sum up, this is useful as a **comment and hint to the programmer.** If you **know** you **will** and **want to** use this function with statically sized arrays only, then I'd absolutely recommend doing this for readability purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are automatically converted to a pointer to its first element when used as function argument, so this function signature:

```
int testFunc(int iStrangeArray[3])
```

is equivalent to:

```
int testFunc(int iStrangeArray[])
```

or

```
int testFunc(int *iStrangeArray)
```

The size of the array is ignored, it's only useful as a signal to the programmer, not to the compiler. As for the *why*, because it's what the C standard says.

Comment: as self commented to my question something about it would make a difference on 2d or higher dimensional arrays, could you explain that if hes right?

Comment: @YuHao Certainly not with `func(int *arr[10])`. Much more `func(int (*arr)[10])`.

Comment: @YuHao You comparison is incorrect. `void func(int arr[10][10]) == void func(int arr[][10]) != void func(int *arr[10])`

Comment: @self. & user3477950 Ah yes, I got it wrong in the comment, deleted. Thanks both for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

That may be a hint to readers that the length of `iStrangeArray` should be three, therefore it could act like part of the API documentation.

However, just like any other documentations that cannot be verified by compilers (or other tools), when the related code evolved, documentations and the code they tried to explain may become asynchronous, at this time (and it looks like this is exactly what happened in your case), this "documantation" could become misleading and will confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at what `int iStrangeArray[3]` is in your function, you'll see this is still just a pointer. As you may know, pointers have no idea about the size of the area they point at, maybe except for the data type of a single element. So yes, technically it does not make difference if you replace it with `int iStrangeArray[]` or `int *iStrangeArray`. However, this may be of much use for readability of your code.